Persistent scent in bedroom from floor coating
I've been living in my house for 7 years and one of the bedrooms always has a strong, perfume-like scent that has persisted since I moved in despite proper ventilation, as if a small incense candle has been burning in the room all along. The entire floor in this room has a transparent layer on it, which I suspect might be some kind of sealant or coating. The floor also feels rougher than the floors in the other rooms.
I've tried ventilating the room well, but the scent remains as strong as ever. I'm curious if anyone has encountered a similar situation or might know what this coating could be and how I can effectively remove or neutralize the scent.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Removing scent from room can be hard.
First start from remove all furniture(and carpets) from this room and check that helped. Testing each part o furniture can find wich one is source of scent.
If this is not furniture then paint walls and celling, then find what can do with floor - there is possibility that perfume/scent source is under floor or in cracks(someone spilled something) that means replacement of floor or if this is wooden one then sanding and new layer of floor varnish will be necessary. For be sure replace all installations like light, switches, sockets, curtain rods and so on.
Are You sure(really sure) that scent is not result of activity of one of Yours fellow residents or neighbors? 7 years is mostly enough to remove most scents.

I'm the only one living in the house and because of the scent the room is rarely used, and yes the floor is still off-gassing the fumes after 7 years...

The room is almost empty too. I wanted to make it an office now, that's why I need to get rid of the scent ASAP...

Then try my advice.  If none helps then next step is redoing walls, floor and celling. If not help then last step is demolition and rebuilding house.
